# Android MediaScannerConnection new instance in Activity class throws Exception

Tags: android, eclipse, nullpointerexception, oncreate, android-mediascanner

I am a few steps away from creating my first android app but there seems to be a problem, which I cannot solve by myself... I need a lil bit help!! :D

So, in my main activity I want to declare like so:

```
    MediaScannerConnection con 
       = new MediaScannerConnection(getApplicationContext(), this);
```

I am using the variable "con" in the onCreate() method and implemented the MediaScannerConnectionClient interface to work with it.

It isn't possible for me to declare the "con" in the onCreate() method because when I do so and the user changes screen orientation, the runtime kills the activity and calls onCreate() again (like we all know :D) and this causes my app to not finish the scan...

Compiling works well! But when I start my app logcat throws this at my head:

```
    02-22 06:03:34.550: E/AndroidRuntime(925): java.lang.RuntimeException: 
    Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo 
    {com.krustbrot.app/com.krustbrot.app.MediaRefresherAct}:
    java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Please help me! My first project guys!!! I really tried hard to fix that issue but can overcome it... :(

Btw sry for my language... :)

Greets!